# Configure New Relic so that newrelic.jar and newrelic.yml don't need to be collocated

Tags: newrelic

I got New Relic instrumentation working with my Java/Mule ESB application.  Everything works great (running in Eclipse at least).

However, since I already have the New Relic jar files in my Maven repository, I don't want to check in another version of the New Relic agent jar in my project.  From [what I've read in the New Relic documentation](https://newrelic.com/docs/java/java-agent-manual-installation) the New Relic agent jar and the newrelic.yml should be in the same directory, but I want to have the newrelic.yml in my project and reference the New Relic agent jar in my Maven repository.

Something like a JVM argument that specifies the newrelic.yml (like it currently is with the javaagent) would be great.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the New Relic support team (quick reply, by the way!):

> 1) You can set the system property newrelic.config.file to the fully
>   qualified path of your newrelic configuration file. The property can
>   be found on the docs site here:https://newrelic.com/docs/java/java-agent-configuration#System_Properties
>
> 2) You must have a newrelic.yml configuration file even if you are
>   relying on server-side config.